# Preventing lock screen from showing on wake-up?

Tags: android, lockscreen, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I'm building an alarm app. I have it so a broadcastreceiver acquires a wakelock and starts the alarm activity. These are the flags I'm using:

Wakelock:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                                   PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                                   PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, ctx.getPackageName());
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON + 
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD +
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED + 
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

What happens is that the activity gets called correctly, but then the lock screen gets called which fires the onPause on my activity. My activity then shows in front of the lock screen. So the overall behavior is the screen flickers on, then off, then back on. This causes my activity to go onCreate -> onResume -> onPause -> onResume. I would like to avoid the onPause if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Alarm manager -> BroadcastReceiver -> `onReceive(){/* your wakelock code*/}`?

Comment: That is correct. After the wakelock code, the onReceive calls the Activity.

Comment: Is the wakelock a field of the receiver ? or a local variable ?

Comment: Yes, the wakelock is a field of the receiver.

Comment: Then probably the phone is falling asleep again once onReceive returns - can it be the case ?

Comment: Yes, that is the case, but only when the lock screen is present. Without a lock screen, it doesn't do that.

Comment: So you need to keep the phone awake till your activity starts ?

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that the lock screen is stealing away the foreground focus, thus making my activity do onCreate -> onResume -> (lock screen steals focus) -> onPause -> (activity dismisses lock screen) -> onResume.

Comment: I suspect the behavior is because the phone falls asleep again and the lock screen pops up - to avoid this you need to start your activity with a static method from the receiver to acquire a static wake lock belonging to your activity. On the other hand maybe a simple `lock.disableKeyguard();` in your onResume() would suffice ? `KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); lock.disableKeyguard();`